# Android app to manually log personal health data

Tags: android, health

I have a **body composition monitor** and a **blood pressure monitor** that can measure various health parameters. What I'd need is an Android app that, for a given day and time, would enable me to input the following data by hand:

- Weight
- BMI
- Body Fat
- Skeletal muscle
- Resting metabolism
- Visceral fat
- Systolic blood pressure
- Diastolic blood pressure
- Pulse rate

The data collected should be saved on the device in a open human-readable text file (ideally CSV) so that I can easily import it into a spreadsheet.

A plus would be the ability to upload (automatically) the data on the cloud (e.g. on Dropbox) and plot charts of those parameters over time directly in the app.

I'd prefer a free or open source app, but I could also choose a paid app if it meets all my requirements.

*I know I could just use a spreadsheet, but I'd like to have something more mobile-friendly that can be used on a phone with a good user experience.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like that such app does not exist (yet). Most apps allow for the collection of *either* the blood pressure and pulse rate *or* weight and BMI. A few apps can track both but that's not enough for me since I need to log extra parameters such as body fat, etc..

In the end, even though it's not what I wanted to use, **I'll log the data using a spreadsheet on the device**. Basically, it's just a simple table where each row contains the date, time and the measurement for each parameter.
It's not ideal but actually not too bad: using [Google Sheets](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.docs.editors.sheets) for Android I've created and prepared the spreadsheet on my desktop computer, making sure the cells are of the right size when read/edited on a smartphone.

The spreadsheet is accessible on the device even when it's **offline** ("Keep offline" option) and can be easily downloaded on a desktop computer for all the processing required (e.g. creation of charts).